# SalesInvoiceFactory does not contain definition for Create‏

Tags: c#, api, sdk

I would like to ask why I am getting the above error when using the following for integrating with Sage SDK:

```
sales_invoice_factory = Company.Factories.SalesInvoiceFactory;
SalesInvoice invoice = sales_invoice_factory.Create();
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont have the Sage SDK so i can only assume that that is no method create();

mayby try

```
sales_invoice_factory = Company.Factories.SalesInvoiceFactory;
SalesInvoice invoice = new SalesInvoice();
```

?

Comment: I copied the above from their sample but getting the error when using it in Visual Studio. using SalesInvoice invoice = new SalesInvoice() throws error too.